# Wordpress thumbnail, timthumb

Tags: wordpress, timthumb

I have a question about my WordPress site. I want to use Timthumb resizer on it. However, thumbnails do not appear. Images aren't shown.

Comment: Uhm I wouldn't do that:
http://wpcandy.com/reports/timthumb-security-vulnerability-discovered/

Comment: Anyway, the question isn't clear. You have to provide more details in an understandable way if possible.

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno - Date on that post is August 3, 2011. Old old news.  It got totally refactored pretty shortly after that and has been through numerous versions since.  There are other options though, Aqua Resizer and Matthew Ruddy's resizer both use built in WP functions.

Comment: Uh, well better! Of what software are you talking about anyway? This? http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need activate the cache folder for timthumb, and need add some privilege, like 755, only to the www-data user.
thats its!
* please, never use 777 for cache folder.

Comment: Exp: my site: erenkeskin.com

Now, I add timthumb code but thumb images don't show.